# Neo4j's shortest path uses cached data

Tags: database, caching, neo4j, shortest-path

I'm using neo4j and shortestPath with where clause for searching optimal path. For some reason shortestPath ignores latest updates in neo4j (although I've disabled query caching and use replan everytime). 
What would you suggest to keep it touch with the latest changes in DB?

Comment: How do you know that your query doesn't take the last updates of your graph ?  Normally it should.

Comment: @logisima it takes only after a couple of seconds and it is critical for me to get the correct shortest path at once as update has been performed.

Comment: We're using java neo4j driver, probably we are facing some issue there, because via restful endpoints everything works correctly

Comment: Just to note, query plan caching shouldn't be involved here, it does not cache results of a query, just the plan generated from the query, and execution of shortestPath() is a part of that plan; the plan should not change as a result of graph changes and a new possible shortest path.

Comment: Are you using clustering? If so, what type?

Comment: Thanks, guys, there wasn't any issue with neo4j, we had the bug in the code.